# Is there a way to test web application using Selenium and either Driver Firefox or Chrome on a server Centos7 without graphical interface?

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

On my local machine, I arrived to test my applications with Selenium with any problems.

But, when I'm doing the same operations on a server Centos7 (I have no graphical interface), I've many errors such as web element not found.

I'm using Docker containers for selenium (hub and nodes). The installation is OK and I can see my drivers on Http://:4444/grid/console.

Does Selenium require a graphical interface for its work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Selenium requires the browser GUI to be present - which is also called viewport.

If you want that Selenium execution happen, without the browser GUI to be present, then you need to use a `headless` browser, which , as the name suggests is `headless`, which means there would be no GUI for them.

Examples of these `headless` browser include `PhantomJS`- [link](http://phantomjs.org/). Now `Chrome` also has a `headless` mode - [link](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome), which you can specify using `ChromeOptions`. Cheers!